# Is it possible to keep Randy from being violently anally probed? What happens if you're successful?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

When you're on the spaceship and have to play a game of "Simon" with the controller while watching Randy get anally probed, the game deliberately throws a fast and difficult sequence to follow. Presumably this is so the player can't understand what button to press at all, causing Randy to get violently anal-probed.

Suppose you somehow caught the sequence (or someone screen-captured it and you followed that sequence) and put it in correctly. (This does imply that the sequence is deterministic and not randomized.) What would happen to Randy?

Comment: Until that day comes I guess we will never know and Randy is going to get plugged up. Try google or youtube, maybe there you can find a video.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you can't prevent Randy from being violently anal probed.

The game deliberately makes it impossible by requiring multiple colors to be pressed simultaneously, while only recognizing one color pressed at a time.

Comment: It also sets up a pretty decent punchline by giving you the simplest command in the world after a couple rounds of that. :P